# Numpy Matrix from Indices

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a matrix consisting of three columns and ten raws, wherein the first and second columns the indices of another matrix (actually an image) are saved. The values of each image cell are saved in the third column. By the way, not all cells have a value!

```
In[11] u = np.array([2, 0, 1, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 9, 8])   # Column indicies of a grid (matrix)
In[12] v = np.array([0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3])   # Raw indicies of a grid (matrix) 
In[13] r = np.random.randn(10)   # grid cell value
In[25]: uvr = np.vstack((u, v, r)).T
In[26]: uvr
Out[25]:
array([[ 2.  ,  0.  ,  0.7 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.09],
       [ 1.  ,  2.  , -0.17],
       [ 5.  ,  2.  ,  1.18],
       [ 6.  ,  1.  , -1.3 ],
       [ 3.  ,  1.  , -0.28],
       [ 4.  ,  4.  , -1.88],
       [ 7.  ,  4.  , -0.19],
       [ 9.  ,  3.  , -0.86],
       [ 8.  ,  3.  ,  1.94]])
```

Now I want to create an image and assign the corresponding value to each cell depending on the cell indices. Right now I do it through for-loop:

```
img = np.zeros((10, 10))
for i, _ in enumerate(uvr):
    uu = u[i]
    vv = v[i]
    img[uu, vv] = r[i]
```

Unfortunately, it takes too long, since the above scenario is just exemplary and my real image is much bigger. Is there any way to convert the mentioned three-column matrix into an image without for-loop, by **just using NumPy functions**?

I am also aware of list-comprehension, but since I do some intermediate calculations, list-comprehension is not really a solution.

thanks

Comment: I might be missing something. Can you not just do `img[u, v] = r`?

Comment: @tomjin I actually tried it but since there are some intermediate calculations (function calls) I thought there may be some NumPy magic functions, with some lamda-parameters :), but I got solved by precalculating the indices and values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `u` and `v` to index, then `r` to assign values to those indices

```
>>> img[u, v] = r
>>> img
array([[ 0.09,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  , -0.17,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.7 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  , -0.28,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -1.88,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  1.18,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  , -1.3 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.19,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.94,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , -0.86,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```